# CMake space delimited list of objects

Tags: cmake

**$<TARGET_OBJECTS:objLib>** this CMake genex gives **semi-colon
separated** list of objects in an object library.

I need to set **space delimited** list of objects in a variable and use the variable in **add_custom_target**

I have tried using string replace in a separate cmake file, call that cmake by passing **$<TARGET_OBJECTS:objLib>** as an argument. But I don't know how to return the new string.

I tried setting the new string as ENV variable and use it in add_custom_target but it didnt work.

can some one please help me resolve this ?

Comment: I'm fairly certain making it a space delimited list will not do what you expect it to, as it will still be passed as a single argument. You probably want to use the `COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS` option in `add_custom_target` / `add_custom_command` instead.

Comment: Do really need a space separated list? Why not a list that you can split to be some program arguments? `I have tried using string replace` Please post the source code of what have you tried.

Comment: @Corristo Awesome !! That's exactly what i wanted.. Thanks a lot.